# Endless Chrome console warnings

Tags: google-chrome

I'm getting the same warnings infinitely in the Chrome console (currently at 73k and counting):

**ComChannels.ChromeComChannel.Content [WARN ] - _onContentPortDisconnected: Never connected -> Error in connection.**

**content.Dispatcher [WARN ] - onComChannelConnectionFailed: Called: timeout**

My website runs fine but I can't tell myself this isn't a problem with my code. Any ideas what these Warnings refer to?

EDIT: Built my website with GGTS, running Grails 2.4.3 and my JDK is 1.7. Running Twitter Bootstrap and JQuery

Comment: Restart with extensions disabled, if that fixes, enable one by one to id the culprit.

Comment: I didn't even notice it was happening on other websites.... I feel dumb. Thank you Alex!

Comment: so this has nothing to do with grails?  then please remove the tag.